# SwiftUI picker title?

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker, swiftui-picker

I'm trying to use the `Picker` for a simple selection. Currently I'm using the `.inline` navigation bar for showing the titles. (here's where i got the example https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/pickers-in-forms)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    @State private var selectedStrength = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< strengths.count) {
                        Text(self.strengths[$0])
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Parent Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

So my issue is that when I go into the picker, there is no title?
[image: Screenshot 1]

When I try to set the inline title on the `Picker`, or `ForEach` or even the `Text`s inside the foreach, the Parent Title gets overridden...

Is there a nice way of fixing this problem or should i just go ahead and make my own picker (any good simple pickers our there)?

Comment: You need to set the `navigationBarTitle` for the `Picker` object as well. And of course the parent title gets overwritten. UINavigationBar doesn't show two titles.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I tried that, it overrides the Parent Title and still doesn't show on the actual picker screen :(

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320934/change-navigation-title-of-picker-in-swiftui ?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I just tried it and it worked...! thank you

Comment: Sadly it didn’t work for me in Xcode 12 beta 5.

Comment: @vacawama well, I'm working on XCode 11.6 as my project has some constraints... :(

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing (got the idea from [Change Navigation Title of Picker in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320934/change-navigation-title-of-picker-in-swiftui) thanks to  `Claus Jørgensen`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    @State private var selectedStrength = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< strengths.count) {
                        Text(self.strengths[$0])
                    }.navigationBarTitle("Strength", displayMode: .inline)
                }.navigationBarTitle("Parent Title", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also change the parent title to "Strength" when the user taps on the back button.